# Javascript recursive function proceeds differently in either case

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

The problem is that when you start the test with 0, after entering if `console.log ("HI!");` the fact that it is running.

But when you start the test with 3, `console.log("HI!");` it exits the loop without running it.

What's the difference? Either way it goes into if, but in one it continues to read the codes after if, in the other it does not read the codes after if.

I think this is a bug in javascript.
Can anyone explain the difference?

```
function test(numb){
  if(numb == 3) {
    return console.log("Finish!");
  } else {
    test(numb = numb + 1);
  };
  return console.log("HI!");
};

test(0)
```

Comment: First introduce the problem, then post the relevant code.

Comment: Because the first branch has "return", and the other doesn't. Returns exits the function.

Comment: Why do you `return` the return value of `console.log()` (which is always `undefined`)?

Comment: in JavaScript, use '===' instead of '=='

Comment: Why would it print "HI!" when you call it with 3 as the argument? Execution begins, branch is evaluated, numb == 3 is true, so it calls `console.log` and returns exactly like the code specifies. End of story. What is surprising about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized the code.

```
function test(numb){
  if(numb === 3) { 
    console.log("Finish!"); // line 3
    return; // line 4
  }
  test(++numb); // line  6
  console.log("HI! " + numb); // line 7
};
```

(1) when numb = 3,

- line 3: print  "Finish!"
- line 4: return. we exit the function.

(2) when numb = 0, the output is :

```
"Finish!"

3

2

1
```

first, we call test(0), test(0) will be pushed onto the memory stack, in line6, test(1) will be called, also, test(1) will be pushed onto the stack, where local variable numb becomes 1, ...at last, test(3) will be called, line 3 and line 4 will be executed, "Finish!" will be printed and then we will return to test(2),which are still on the stack, and 3 will be printed. Then we return to test(1)...finally, we return to test(0),where 1 will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly or not but when the test function run with parameter 3, it shouldn't return `console.log("HI!");` because you put `return console.log("Finish!");` **return** will return the value and stop the function

Comment: You're right, when I start it with 3 anyway it doesn't return `console.log (" HI! "); '.

But when I start it with 0 it returns 'console.log ("HI!");'.

Why do I get results differently although the condition is met either way?

Comment: because in else condition you don't return anything you just call the same function then will complete the function, if you put return like this return test(numb = numb + 1); the function will stop and console.log("HI!"); will not showing ever